# Delphi 10.2, зарисовка границ таблицы в MicrosoftWord

Tags: delphi

У меня есть функция, с помощью котрой я вставляю в MSWord таблиц:

```
function CreateTable(ANumRows, ANumColumns: integer;
                     var ATableID: integer): boolean; export;
var
  sel_: variant;
begin
  CreateTable := true;
  try
    sel_ := Words_Templs.selection;
    Words_Templs.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range := sel_.Range, NumRows := ANumRows, NumColumns := ANumColumns);
    ATableID := Words_Templs.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count;
  except
    CreateTable := false;
  end;
end;
```

Таблица в Word вставляется, но **с прозрачными** границами.
Макрос (в Word) для зарисовки границ (черные линии), выдал:

```
With Selection.Borders(wdBorderTop)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(wdBorderLeft)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(wdBorderRight)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
```

Я попробовал в Delphi 10.2, создать такой же код:

```
    sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(1).LineStyle := 1;
sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(1).LineWidth := 2;
sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(1).Color := 0;


sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(2).LineStyle := 1;
sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(2).LineWidth := 2;
sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(2).Color := 0;

sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(3).LineStyle := 1;
sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(3).LineWidth := 2;
sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(3).Color := 0;


sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(4).LineStyle := 1;
sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(4).LineWidth := 2;
sel_.Cells.Borders.Item(4).Color := 0;
```

но так я делаю видимой только одну ячейку. А мне нужно всю таблицу сделать видимой

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Несколько странно, имея код, который использует свойство Borders у всего выделения, менять его на использование Cells

Comment: И еще более странно пользоваться сомнительными константами вместо официальных https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211923(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @kami, а что вы имеете ввиду под сомнительными константами - "LineStyle", "LineWidth", "Color"? так я вроде все правильно указал...

Answer (score 0):

Все проще:

```
begin
  LSel.Tables.Item(1).Borders.item(-1).LineStyle:=1;
  LSel.Tables.Item(1).Borders.item(-2).LineStyle:=1;
  LSel.Tables.Item(1).Borders.item(-3).LineStyle:=1;
  LSel.Tables.Item(1).Borders.item(-4).LineStyle:=1;
  LSel.Tables.Item(1).Borders.item(-5).LineStyle:=1;
  LSel.Tables.Item(1).Borders.item(-6).LineStyle:=1;
end;
```